# Export Heroku Postgres database, but exclude a table

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I want to get an export of my Heroku application's Postgres database, however I want to exclude one table.  Is this possible?

Here is the command I use to export my entire Postgres database:

```
$ PGUSER=my_username PGPASSWORD=my_password heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL my-application-name`
```

Maybe there is a way to exclude one table, or specify a list of tables to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal pg dump command you can specify the tables to include with -t option and exclude tables with -T option.

Can you try this :

```
$  PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -T *table you want to exclude* -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

Comment: @Donny P if it worked for you then Kindly mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Muhammed, the bounty expires in 2 days and I will give it to the best answer at that time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the document copied from postgreql official document.

-T table
  --exclude-table=table

Do not dump any tables matching the table pattern. The pattern is interpreted according to the same rules as for -t. -T can be given more than once to exclude tables matching any of several patterns.

When both -t and -T are given, the behavior is to dump just the tables that match at least one -t switch but no -T switches. If -T appears without -t, then tables matching -T are excluded from what is otherwise a normal dump.

here is link for your reference
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html